# ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'responses -> response' ( Angular 8) FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, primeng, formarray

I am trying to use FormArray to get the value of inputs that has iterated with for loop. I have used primeng table.The code is as follows

**AppComponent HTML**

```
<div formArrayName="responses">
  <p-table [value]="datas">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr style="border: none;">
            <th>Question No</th>
            <th>Questions</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data #input>
      <tr>
        <td>{{data.id}} </td>
        <td [ngClass]="{'objectiveClass' : datas.Type != 'Narrative','narrativeClass':datas.Type == 'Narrative'}">{{ data.Question }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="datas.Type != 'Narrative'">
            <input class="form-control"
             id="objective"
             type="number"
             (keyup)="patternChecking(number)"
             formControlName="response"
             #number/>
        </td>
  <td *ngIf="datas.Type == 'Narrative'">
            <textarea #narrative rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="5000" 
            formControlName="response"
            (keyup) ="charactersRemaining()"
            ></textarea>
            <span  *ngIf = "isCharactersRemaining">
                <em>{{ textMaxLength - narrative.value.length }} characters remaining</em></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
</div>
```

**AppComponent TS**

```
 this.responseForm = this.fb.group({
    responses : this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
      response:new FormControl ('')
    })])
   });
```

I am not able to identify the issue with the code above.

[image]

Comment: why two `this.fb`?

Answer (score 0):

The API for FormArray is really clunky. You actually have to iterate over each control inside of the FormArray. Something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let control of responseForm.get('responses').controls; let i = index">
     <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input
             formControlName="response"
          />
     </div>
</div>
```